# destroysurface logcat error on closing an activity

Tags: android

Whenever an activity closes I get a logcat error:

```
Input channel constructed: fd=81
11:13:26.188  D  Input channel destroyed: fd=84
11:13:26.188  D  MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
11:13:26.188  D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@b80b1eb[Splash_GameActivity]
11:13:26.189  D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
11:13:26.211  D  eglDestroySurface = 0x8ea05360, 0x8eb5e800
11:13:26.236  D  Relayout returned: old=[462,305][817,527] new=[462,305][817,527] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
11:13:26.245  D  stopped(true) old=false
11:13:26.254  D  dispatchDetachedFromWindow
11:13:26.270  D  Input channel destroyed: fd=82
11:13:26.460  E  win=Window{d4f7368 u0 com.scorer.tennis_android_nov22_nov22/com.scorer.tennis_android_nov22.Splash_GameActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:896 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:877 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5533 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:320 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5957 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:100
```

The code is:

```
package com.scorer.tennis_android_nov22;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
public class Splash_GameActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_game);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method
            @Override
            public void run() {
            // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000); // wait for 1 second
    }
}
```

It does not appear to cause a problem but is annoying.

Developed in Android Studio Dolphin - sdk 30

Comment: I have the same error and I have no idea how to dig deeper. I also use Runnable with a Handler similar to you in one of my Activities

Comment: What device are you using? I found it cause only on Samsung devices.